# How to write a cell array of cell array with a header into a text file?

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation, text-files, cell-array

I have a header as a row vector (`gene_common` of size 1*12725) and I want to write it into a text file with its corresponding cell array (`X1` of size 1*217  and its nested cell array 1*12728).
I want to insert this header from cell 4 of `X1` (`X1` has 12728 columns so the header will start from cell 4 to 12728).

[image]
[image]

I tried this code:

```
fid5= fopen('fileX.txt', 'w');
temp = vertcat(gene_common, X1{:}).';
fmt = [repmat('%s,', 1, length(X1)), '%s\n'];
fprintf(fid5, fmt, temp{:});
fclose(fid5);
```

but I got this error :

> Error using `vertcat`
>   
> CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
>
> Error in endfile (line 22)
>   
> `temp = vertcat(GENE_common,X1{:}).';`

Comment: It's written as `gene_common` in your code but the error capitalises the first part of the variable: `GENE_common`.  This may be due to a simple misuse of variables.  Please verify that the code and the error are consistent - specifically, please make sure that the variables reported in the error and your code are the same.

Comment: Non is GENE_comon its my mistake

Comment: the code is ok i wrote wrong

Comment: all the variables are well defined and there are no undefined varibles but still getting the same error

Comment: Any one could help me ???

Comment: You have inconsistent dimensions. The gene common variable has 12725 columns but the cells in X1 have 12728 columns.

Comment: @ rayryeng Thanks i got it

Answer (score 0):

```
    fid5= fopen('file.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid5, repmat('%s\t', [1 col]),'','','',GENE_common{1,:});
fprintf(fid5,'\n');
for h1=1:217
    fprintf(fid5, '%s\t ', X{h1}{:});
    fprintf(fid5,'\t');
    fprintf(fid5,'\n');
end
fclose(fid5);
```